# Authorize annotation accepting tokens from different localhost Identity Server Authorities

Tags: identityserver3, authorize

Right now I'm developing a SSO service using Identity Server 3.

I was looking into something with reference tokens using one of the sample projects and then I noticed that the cookie from the sample project was authorizing the user on my project.

The project is still in development so I'm still using the test x509 certificate provided by the IDS project. They are both running on my local machine. Also I'm still using "secret" as the secret. The sample project was the minimal web host.

In my mind I was assuming that the reason this was happening was some combination of the x509 certificate, the fact they're both running on localhost, and the fact they have the same secrets. But I wanted to make sure.

Here's my IDS Host setup:

```
app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp => {
var factory = Factory.Configure();
factory.ConfigureCustomUserService("CustomMembershipReboot");
idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions {
SiteName = "Embedded IDS",
SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
{EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true},
Factory = factory }); });
```

(the factory is similar to the one provided in the membership reboot tie in)

Client:

```
ClientName = "MVC",
ClientId = "mvc",
Flow = Flows.Implicit,
AccessTokenLifetime=60,
RedirectUris = new List{},
PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List {},
AllowedScopes = new List { },
RequireConsent=false,
ClientSecrets = new List{ new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
AccessTokenType=AccessTokenType.Jwt
```

(the clients are at different redirect uri's, i just removed some stuff to make the post shorter)

Comment: I don't quite follow, but the surprise was that a cookie from one app on localhost was being accepted by another app on localhost? That could happen because IIS express will use the same data protection provider for anything with the same host name.

Comment: I figured that it was something like that, but I wasn't sure.